# Replay RTSP video stream from PCAP

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, wireshark, rtsp, pcap

I've got a PCAP file containing all the network traffic received on the client side from a RTSP video streaming. The traffic has been captured using Wireshark and the replay was performed using a SDP file and VLC player.

Is it possible to reproduce the video again using the PCAP file? I guess that maybe it could be possible just extracting the RTP multimedia traffic and replacing destination IP and port, am I wrong? Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically it is rather easy to replay this traffic. You will not be able to emulate double-side communication between your software and camera, but you can easily restore video from camera.

Perhaps ffmpeg will be able to help you. I've written simple tool for flussonic that analyzes recorded traffic.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Max! Actually you're right, it's even easier than I expected. Just opening the SDP file with VLC everything is done. However, do you now if internally VLC acts like the server side or is just extracting the video from given configuration? Thanks for your help!